# parsing price of various format form a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse price out of a string, however the price has a lot of different format that I am trying to capture as best as possible.. here is the code that I have:

```
$pattern = '#([Ii][Dd][Rr].?\s*[0-9.,]+)|([Rr][Pp].?\s*[0-9.,]+)|(\s[0-9]+\s?[Kk]\s)|([0-9]+[Rr][Bb])|([0-9.,]+\s*[Rr][Ii][Bb][Uu])|(\b[0-9]+[.,][0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+)#u';

        if (!$this->price)
        {
            $matches = array();
            preg_match($pattern, $caption, $matches);
            if (isset($matches[0]))
            {           

                $price = $matches[0];   
                $price = preg_replace("#[K|k]|[R|r][B|b]#", "000", $price); 
                $price = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $price); 

                if (strlen($price) > 7)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                $price = floatval($price);  

                if ($price < 1000)
                {
                    $price *= 1000;
                }

                $this->price = $price; 

                //Remove finded price
                $this->caption = preg_replace($pattern, '', $caption, 1);
                $result = true;
            } 
        }
```

and here is the price string:

```
Peacock long blouse Bahan combat, fit to XXL, pj77cm, Ld120cm, berat 0,21kg, Hitam, body pjg, ukuran besar 71.000 (blm + ongkir)// stock terbatas sistaa......
```

however this returns me 21.000 because it parses the 0.21kg string as price. How do I avoid 0, or 0. as a price detection into the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

```
([Ii][Dd][Rr].?\s*[0-9.,]+)|([Rr][Pp].?\s*[0-9.,]+)|(\s[0-9]+\s?[Kk]\s)|([0-9]+[Rr][Bb])|([0-9.,]+\s*[Rr][Ii][Bb][Uu])|(\b[1-9]+[.,][0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+)
```

Try this.See demo.`,21kg` was being captured by the `6th` groups of your regex `(\b[0-9]+[.,][0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+)`.Changed that to `(\b[1-9]+[.,][0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+)` to exclude `0,` and `0.`.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/36